# How to display form elements based on radio button selection

Tags: php, yii

I'm creating a new application where in I'm designing a form where the elements differ based on the selection of radiobuttonlist.
For example -
I have a radiobutton list -
Gender and options are Male and Female.

**For Male:**
Next element of the form will be textfield **Extra Curricular activities:** and students can type anything like Judo,Karate,etc.

**For Female:**
Next element of the form will be Dropdown Menu **Extra Curricular activities:** has options Dance, Ballet, etc
Based on the selection of the above radiobuttons the next elements should be displayed and the data entered will be converted into JSON format and stored in Database.

Now, to achieve this I have put the same field as dropdownlist in one div and the textfield in another div. I use jQuery to hide and show div respectively.

Note - Extra Curricular activities is used as textfield for Male children and dropdown for Female children.
Am I doing the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This feels a bit hacky, but here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3s8wM/

```
here's my "accompanied code" to make SO happy about jsfiddle links :P
```

What I did here was basically what you're already doing, with the difference that I'm moving the elements you don't want posted out of the form into a hidden div.

My recommendation would be to do it a bit differently, though. Why limit the female options to a dropdown while the male options are completely open? I think you're asking for trouble here - you don't want your users to feel you're being biased toward any gender.

I would opt for a dropdown for both male and female with an additional "Other..." selection. If they select that option, then show a textarea for them to add activities to. This way, you will have the same form elements to process for either male or female, and will make your development easier and more maintainable.

**EDIT**

To answer your question "Is this the right way to do this?", I would think not. Since you have both the textarea and the select element with the same name, you may get odd results in your $_POST variable, which is why I opted to move the elements outside of the form if you don't plan on using them when you process the $_POST variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply joseph. But, my question is can I do it as I have suggested in the post above. Is it the right way to do it?

Comment: @user3004356 to answer your question, I would think not. Since you have both the textarea and the select element with the same name, you may get odd results in your `$_POST` variable, which is why I opted to move the elements *outside* of the form if you don't plan on using them when you process the `$_POST` variable.

Comment: I don't see your question in the original post, but in the comment in this answer. Can you update your post to avoid confusion.